# ¿Es posible decir la frase "Déjame libre que te recompensaré"?

Tags: imperativo

En portugués brasileño, es posible decir una frase como "Me liberta que eu te recompenso", con el significado de "si me dejas libre, te recompensaré". ¿La frase equivalente en español "déjame libre que te recompensaré", con el significado semejante a "déjame libre y te recompensaré" (con el "que" en lugar del "y"), es posible o suena rara? Gracias.

Comment: Ambas son correctas. Con 'y' puede interpretarse como un condicional. Si deseas plantear una elección. Una disyuntiva. Con 'que' puede interpretarse como una consecuencia ineludible. Sin disyuntivas. Causa-efecto

Comment: @Laiv tu comentario es muy bueno y seguro que da para una respuesta. ¿Te animas a publicarla? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de responder, matizar que mi respuesta tiene por contexto el español que se habla en España y cualquiera de las siguientes frases se entendería perfectamente.

> ¿La frase equivalente en español "déjame libre que te recompensaré", con el significado semejante a "déjame libre y te recompensaré" (con el "que" en lugar del "y"), es posible o suena rara?

Ambas son correctas. Creo que en cualquier punto de la península se entendería su significado.

> con el "que" en lugar del "y"

Cambiar el "que" por el "y" es posible, aunque **según el contexto pueden aportar matices diferentes al discurso**.

> Si me dejas libre, te recompensaré.

- Se expresa una condición, se propone una elección. El *protagonista* se siente capaz (o con ánimos) de negociar su libertad.
- A su vez, hay implícita un *disyuntiva*.

  *Si me dejas libre, te recompensaré. **Si no lo haces, ...***

> Déjame libre, y te recompensaré.

- Es exactamente el mismo escenario que el anterior. Hay intención de negociar. Pero aquí el *protagonista* parece más resuelto, más seguro de sí mismo.
- *Déjame libre, y te recompensaré. **Si no lo haces, ...***

> Déjame libre, que te compensaré.

- De esta frase se desprende cierta **insistencia**. Quizá ya se ha intentado negociar varias veces y nuestro *protagonista* insiste en que si se le libera habrá recompensa.

Estos son ejemplos válidos para las tres frases pero se podrían formular más. Dependería del *contexto* y del **estado de ánimo** de la persona que habla.

Comment: ¡Qué bien que contestes! Nótese que [corregí una errata tipográfica](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/18144/revisions) pero al mismo tiempo tú añadiste/eliminaste algo, por lo que creo que hay un conflicto. Si puedes, revisa que no se perdiera nada de lo que añadiste al final.

Comment: Todo correcto :-). Espero que la respuesta sea de utilidad. Aun que da para muchos más ejemplos e interpretaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Ambas son correctas, sin embargo la respuesta depende del sentido original de la oración.

```
Déjame libre que te recompensaré.
```

La oración tiene el tono imperativo, formada por una orden y una promesa.

```
Déjame libre y te recompensaré.
```

Al incluir la conjunción *y* la oración se compone de condicionante y condición.

Un ejemplo distinto, donde la diferencia se aprecia mejor.

```
Da otro paso y te mataré.
```

La acción de *matar* depende de la condicionante.

```
Da otro paso que te mataré.
```

La oración es totalmente imperativa.

Answer (score -2):

Es rara e incorrecta. Aunque en entornos informales puede tener un pase (hasta los nativos usan la *que* cuando no toca).

Lo mejor es usar la conjunción *y*, el significado de la frase no cambie y será  correcta para todo el mundo.